# Manage Storage says documents uses 12gb, when they don't add up to 12gb

Tags: macos, storage

I am observing my storage breakdown by going to *About This Mac > Storage > Manage*.

From within there, on the left side it lists Applications, Books, and Documents on the left.

It indicates that my Documents uses up 12 gb. When I then click on that entry, the right side pane displays the options of *Large Files, Downloads, Unsupported Apps, Container, File Browser*.

When I browse through all these options, the amount of files listed in all of them cumulatively does come close to 12 gb. More like 1 gb total.

So how I am supposed to understand where these 12 gb of documents are when it doesn't list any of them.

Also my trash in emptied.

I feel like mac is like "You have a tonne of files, but try to find them..." lol.

Answer (score 0):

This Apple function is not very reliable. If you want to know in detail the occupation of your user space, instead use [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) which will give you all the details.